# NGINX redirection with CNAME

Tags: nginx, https, cname-record, redirection

It's my first time using NGINX and I running into some trouble.

So I have a A record pointing to test.example.com and I created a CNAME toto.example.com redirecting to test.example.com
test.example.com is working fine. When I get access to it, I am redirected to test.example.com/mysite (I made a redirection on NGINX).
I also need to mention that my NGINX is redirecting every request in HTTPS (with a Let's  Encrypt certificate).

The thing that I want is, when I go to toto.example.com I want it to be redirected to test.example.com/mysite BUT still having the browser showing toto.example.com/mysite instead of having test.example.com/mysite as the URL.

How can I do that please? Find bellow my NGINX config (I only have one site setup). Please, keep in mind that every request must be sent in HTTPS not HTTP.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.example.com;

    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name test.example.com;
    root /var/www;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/my/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/my/key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/my/certificate;

    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
       return 301 https://test.example.com/mysite;
    }

    location /sitetwo {
       index index.php;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /sitetwo/index.php;
    }

    location /sitethree{
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:11334/;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /mysite {
       index index.php;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /mysite/index.php;

    }

    location ~ ^/mysite/(README|INSTALL|LICENSE|CHANGELOG|UPGRADING)$ {
       deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/mysite/(bin|SQL|config|temp|logs)/ {
       deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
         if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {return 404;}
         fastcgi_pass  unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         include fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a valid certificate for `toto.example.com`?

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for your answer. I only have a certificate for test.example.com

Comment: In your question you state that the browser should show `toto.example.com` in the address bar and that the connection should be over `https`. In which case, the browser will expect a valid certificate for `toto.example.com` or `*.example.com`.

Comment: @RichardSmith I prefer to have a different certificate for each subdomain, for security purposes. After I made that certificate, where should I put it? Do I need to create a new conf file for that subdomain? And put the certificate path there? Thanks!

Comment: The certificate will be configured within a `server` block containing a `server_name toto.example.com;` statement. How you split this across multiple files is up to you.

Comment: When this is done, how do I redirect toto.example.com to test.example.com/mysite in HTTPS? Do I need to use a "return 301" ? And how do I make sure the URL stays toto.example.com?

Comment: If your new `server` block contains similar statements to the `server` block in your question, your site will appear at `toto.example.com/mysite`. URL redirection is one mechanism by which the browser address bar is changed, which you say you do not want to do.

Comment: Ok thanks. So here is the thing now. When I access to toto.example.com I get don't get anything (white page) and the server is sending me a file to download. Find bellow my configuration file for toto.example.com

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!! I put a / at the end of the return 301 URL. Doing so didn't work. So I removed the / and it worked.

I had that:

```
return 301 https://toto.example.com/mysite/;
```

And I did that:

```
return 301 https://toto.example.com/mysite;
```

Now everything is working perfectly! Thank you very much Richard!